# SQL Server During Merge can i store source table value into variable

Tags: t-sql

See my code to understand what i am trying.

```
DECLARE @LI NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @XFundCode VARCHAR(20)


SET @LI = ''  
    
     MERGE INTO TblLineItemTemplate Trg
     USING 
     (
         SELECT MAX(Section) AS Section,
         MAX(LineItem) AS LineItem,
         MAX(XFundCode) AS XFundCode,
         MAX(StandardDate) AS StandardDate,
         MAX(StandardValue) AS StandardValue,
         MAX(ActualProvidedByCompany) AS ActualProvidedByCompany,
         MAX(TickerID) AS TickerID
         FROM #TmpTenQKData
         GROUP BY LineItem    
     ) AS Src 
     ON UPPER(TRIM(Trg.LineItem)) = UPPER(TRIM(Src.LineItem)) AND Trg.TickerID = Src.TickerID
    
     WHEN MATCHED THEN 
         UPDATE SET 
             XFundCode = Src.XFundCode,
             Action = 'U',
             Insertdate = GETDATE()
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
            
         SET @LI=Src.LineItem
         SET @XFundCode = Src.XFundCode
            
         INSERT 
         (
             TickerID,
             LineItem,
             XFundCode,
             Action,
             UserID,
             Insertdate
         )
         VALUES 
         (
             TRIM(@TickerID), 
             TRIM(@LI), 
             TRIM(@XFundCode), 
             'I', @UserID, 
             GETDATE()
         );
```

i want to store this way without OUTPUT clause

```
SET @LI=Src.LineItem
SET @XFundCode = Src.XFundCode
```

is it possible ?

please tell me a way to store source table value into variable during
insert/update from merge statement.

for each insert how can i store source table value by output clause. thanks

Comment: If you want to store the source data insert the data into a table variable or or scalar variables first, and then use those variables in the `MERGE`.

Comment: Otherwise, what do you have against an `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: please show all possible way to store source table data for each insert.

Comment: i already covered that in my first comment.

Comment: @Larnu can you please small code snippet which help me to understand what are you saying.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-merge-to-do-insert-and-update-operations-on-a-table-in-a-single-statement) has one.